# How to process many text files in array of threads c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

There is a directory with some text files which i need to process in some way.
There are 4 threads.
How to process this text files in array of threads?
Any thoughts?

```
int countfiles; //count of files
    int countthreads = 4;
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[countthreads];
    Queue<string> filesqueue = new Queue<string>();
    foreach (string file_to_read in filelist)
    {
        filesqueue.Enqueue(file_to_read); //добавить в очередь файлы из каталога
        countfiles++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < countthreads; i++)
    {
        //how to process text files in array of threads

    }
```

Comment: Why do _want_ an Array of Threads? If you want parallel execution, you can go for more modern approaches like [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) or [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) ...

Comment: @Fildor I don't :D It's a task for my laboratory work in uni. I have to realise it with threads.

Comment: Well, Parallel.ForEach or DataFlow or Task are also realized with threads :o)

Comment: @SirRufo You _know_ what I meant ;D "Abstractions" from plain old threads ... I should have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a brief starter. It should be improved regarding Exception Handling etc. but for you it should be a good starting ground.

```
// considering this is inside a class ...
const int THREADCOUNT = 4;
private Thread[] threads = new Thread[THREADCOUNT]; // Mind: No Threads created, yet!
private BlockingCollection<string> workQueue = 
        new BlockingCollection<string>(new ConcurrentQueue<string>());
        // ^^ ThreadSafe, blocking FIFO, shared by the threads.

// Attention: This method will (probably) return before processing is finished.
private void Process()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++ )
    {
       // create 4 Threads and start them.
       threads[i] = new Thread(WorkerMethod);
       threads[i].Start( );
    }

    // Fill work queue => Will be processed while being filled, already!
    foreach( var fileToRead in filelist ) // <-- using "filelist" from your example...
        workQueue.Add(fileToRead);
    // Signal no more items to process.
    workQeue.CompleteAdding();
}

// Each Thread will run this:
private void WorkerMethod( )
{
    // While queue is not empty or completed
    while( !workQueue.IsCompleted )
    {
         // Queue access is threadsafe: using a ConcurrentQueue behind the scenes.
         string filepath = workQueue.Take(); // Get next item. If none, wait for one.
         ProcessFile(filepath); // TODO: Implement actual processing of file.
    }

    // Mind: when the control flow reaches the end of this method, 
    // the thread will die. You cannot start this instance of the thread 
    // again.

}
```

Mind: After `Process` has been called, it *cannot* be called again. So you should fortify against that. Only after the threads have finished, you could run a cleanup and start over.

You also could add: [Cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netframework-4.8), [ProgressReporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=netframework-4.8) ...

---

EDIT

An alternative would also be to not add every single element, but prefill the queue:

```
private BlockingCollection<string> workQueue; // leave it like this here ...

// ... in between same as above

// instead of "foreach ..."
workQeue = new BlockingCollection<string>(new ConcurrentQueue<string>( filelist ));
// ^^ Assuming "filelist" is-a IEnumerable<string>
// ... rest same as above
```

---

References:

- [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8)
- [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Starting a Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8#Starting)